# How to manage log4j.properties in coding jUnit for web servlet

Tags: tomcat, junit, log4j

I'm developing web servlet and having confusion with log4j.properities,
and I defined to call initialize logger in constructor.

```
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyProject.class.getName());
public MyProject() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = loader.getResource("log4j.properties");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);
}
```

In general, logging file about web servlet refers to tomcat's log directory.

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.base}/logs/myproject.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

But, while coding jUnit for webservlet,
logging file refers to improper address because ${catalina.base} is blank text.
Error log is here.

```
[junit] log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
[junit] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/myproject.log (No such file or directory)
```

So, please teach me wise management about log file.
I hope stopping output log file while testing by jUnit.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231773/specifying-a-custom-log4j-properties-file-for-all-of-junit-tests-run-from-eclips

Answer (score 6):

You should maintain a separate `log4j.properties` for tomcat deployments and unit tests. The unit test `log4j.properties` is likely to be heavier on debug information, whereas the deployment version should minimise logging output to avoid being a drag on performance.

Doing this requires you to juggle the classpath properly, so that the unit test `log4j.properties` is picked up for unit tests, but is not packaged into the WAR.  Conventionally, this goes into `src/test`.

Comment: "minimise logging output to avoid being a drag on performance": and so the important messages (errors, warnings) are not swamped by unimportant messages.