# Specifying a custom log4j.properties file for all of JUnit tests run from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, log4j

I would like to specify a specific Eclipse `VM argument` to all of the JUnit tests I run from Eclipse i.e.

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-dev.properties
```

This is because I want a specific log4j configuration file to be picked up by all my JUnit tests instead of the default `log4j.properties` file.

As of now I have to specify the above `VM argument` (in `Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM arguments`)  for each of my JUnit tests making it cumbersome because I have many tests.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081316/where-is-the-correct-location-to-put-log4j-properties-in-an-eclipse-project

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You do not need to give the JVM a different property name. The logging code searches for the `log4j.properties` file using the classpath. So all you need to do is ensure that your test `log4j.properties` file is in a location that it will find *before* the release file.

I use Maven, which lays out files in directories to make that easy. My release `log4j.properties` goes in the directory `src/main/resources`. My test version goes in `src/test/resources`. The Eclipse build path (classpath) is set up to search `src/test/resources` before `src/main/resources`, so your unit tests use the test file. The JAR (or WAR) build instructions use the files from `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Very neat: I was not aware that the first log4j.properties file in classpath gets used by log4j. Thanks a lot. It works on command line maven too which is great.

Comment: Very good solution. I was wondering if the order can be set via maven directly. So that my developers need not do this config when they import/reimport the project.

Comment: Note: if you're struggling to create the `src/test/resources` directory in Eclipse, this is because of a bug where Eclipse thinks the standard Maven directories automatically exist in some circumstances, but checks whether or not they really exist in others.  Create the directory manually, then close and reopen your Eclipse project, and it should appear in the "Java Resources" tree of your project as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse gives you the ability to define default VM arguments that are applied to any launch which uses that VM. You could use that in your situation by defining a JRE configuration with the VM argument you want for log4j and then setting up all JUnit launches to use that JRE definition.

In Preferences, **Java** > **Installed JREs** and use the **Add...** button to define a JRE. In the **JRE Definition** dialog there is a field for **Default VM arguments**. Give this JRE definition a useful name such as "JDK 7 for JUnit" so that you can easily identify it.

[image]

Then in your JUnit launch(es), on the **JRE** tab, select the JRE definition you created.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot E-Riz: the solution you suggest is great too. +1.