# Disable log4j output during unit-tests

Tags: unit-testing, logging, log4j

It's common practice to obtain loggers via static-factory (though it totally brokes DI principle). And actually it's fine, unless you would like to get rid of logging totally, e.g. while running unit-tests.

I was able to switch off *log4j* logging, by using following spell:

```
 List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger>list(LogManager.getCurrentLoggers());
 loggers.add(LogManager.getRootLogger());
 for (Logger logger : loggers) {
     logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
 }
```

Still it prints some setup info to the console in the very beginning:

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [test] additivity to [false].
log4j: Level value for test is  [DEBUG].
...
```

How do I disable it as well, **programmatically**, while running unit-test suite?

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24315819/545127

Comment: How are you configuring the output for non-test scenarios? Are you using a build system?

Answer (score 21):

You probably have enabled internal log4j logging in your `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file.

Log4j uses a class called [LogLog](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/LogLog.html) to make these internal logging calls.
You can disable LogLog's output by calling `LogLog.setQuietMode(true)`.
This needs to be set *before* the first call to log4j, which triggers initialization. Note, though, that `setQuietMode()` not only disables debug output but also warnings.

I would therefore recommend that you use a separate logging configuration for your tests. [Raedwald](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906389/disable-log4j-output-during-unit-tests#comment40552150_25906389) outlined how to do this in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231773/specifying-a-custom-log4j-properties-file-for-all-of-junit-tests-run-from-eclips/24315819#24315819) they linked to.

Here's an example `log4j.xml` file that you can use. Notice the `debug="false"` property. It's not strictly necessary to set this, though, as the default value is `false`.

If you're using maven, put the file in `src/test/resources`, which will ensure that this file will get picked up for tests instead of your main configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="OFF"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

This is the equivalent `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.debug=false

log4j.rootLogger=OFF, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Putting the xml file fixed it for me, though the properties file didn't work for some reason