# Java: mock multipartfile in unit test

Tags: java, junit, stream

I am trying to mock a MultipartFile and I want to create the mock with a stream that I create in the test

I've tries with a file without much luck either. Here is what I have tried so far

```
FileInputStream stream = new 
FileInputStream("MOCK_file.xlsm");
MultipartFile f1 = new MockMultipartFile("file1",stream);
MultipartFile[] files = {f1};
return files;
```

I get a fileNotFoundException. Where should I put my file in my Maven project so the unit tests can find the file?

-- OR --

How do I just create a stream in code without the use of a file?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32826371/1089967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I just create a stream in code without the use of a file?

You could use a `ByteArrayInputStream` to inject mock data. It's pretty straightforward for a small amount of data:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
```

Otherwise, you need to figure out what directory is your code running from, which is something that depends on how it's being run. To help with that you could print the `user.dir` system property, which tells you the current directory:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Alternatively, you can use a full path, rather than a relative one to find the file.

Answer (score 5):

Even better you can mock only the `MultipartFile` and you will not be needing the `InputStream` at all.

To do so you only need to do `mock(MultiPartFile.class)` and then define what each function will do

For example if you use the name

```java
final MultipartFile mockFile = mock(MultipartFile.class);
when(mockFile.getOriginalFilename()).thenReturn("CoolName");
```

This way you wont have to bother with actual files neither unexpected responses as you will be defining them

Answer (score 1):

Put the file in

```
src/test/resources/MOCK_file.xlsm
```

Read from JUnit class with:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MOCK_file.xlsm");
```